# JavaScript Inside JavaScript in WordPress and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to change hidden input value based on user input in form. I have written code like below

```
<script>

jQuery("body").on("change","#wpforms-250-field_21",function(){
var bookingDate = jQuery('#wpforms-250-field_21').val();

    <?php
            $olddate= "<script>document.writeln(bookingDate);</script>";
            $today = date("d-m-Y");

            $olddate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $olddate);
            $inputdate = $olddate->format('d-m-Y');

            $datetime1 = date_create($today); 
            $datetime2 = date_create($inputdate); 

            $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2); 

            $total_days =$interval->format('%a'); 


                if($total_days>0){
                    $hidden2 =1;
                }
                else{
                    $hidden2 =0;
                }
    ?>

jQuery('#wpforms-250-field_100').val(<?php echo $hidden2; ?>);

}); 

</script>
```

I have issue in line 7, There I have used again javascript, I am not getting other idea for achieve my goal, I am unable to run code because of another javascript inside javascript. Let me know if someone can help me for achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the JavaScript snippet to PHP on line 7 won't work here as the PHP will literally read "document.writeln(bookingDate);".

What I will say is, there is no need for PHP here as everything you want to do can be achieved with pure JavaScript. But if you really want to use PHP, you'd need to look at performing an ajax request, passing through the bookingDate variable as one of the POST fields and then get it to output the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot write php inside javascript, you can write php inside html though, and for jquery you need to use $ as selector. You should refer to jquery documentation. https://api.jquery.com/